# Docker windows container DNS Cache and firewall

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, windows-firewall

I have a Docker windows container and Linux container on a different node. 
On windows, I opened ports in the firewall mentioned here: https://docs.docker.com/network/overlay/#operations-for-all-overlay-networks
(8 rules - 4 for in and 4 for out) but even then when I connect to the container on the windows host and try to ping the Linux container I receive "No such host is known" but after executing (inside the container):

> Clear-DnsClientCache

everything starts to work. 
I also removed the whole stack and tried to disable firewall and surprise - now everything works without clearing the DNS cache. 
Once again I removed the stack and enabled the firewall - again I have to connect to the container and clear the cache to make it work.

Looks like there is something wrong in the firewall settings but what? I did not find any other ports which should be opened

Comment: based on the message it seems that there is a DNS issue did you tried to do a nslookup for some known domain (ex:www.google.com)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I have just found an answer but I do not fully understand it. I have tried to open ports first 0-9999 then 0-5000 then 0-2500 etc and found out that I need to open port 1888 (tcp, in) to make the docker overlay network work immediately (I mean to be able to resolve services DNS names immediately) but I did not find anything about that on the internet. I have no idea why. Was I only one with that problem? Maybe this is not the correct solution? Could someone tell me why this port is needed and why Clear-DnsClientCache works even when 1888 is blocked?

Edit:
Looks like this solution was wrong. Now it just works once and then does not work and then once again works. I can remove and recreate the whole stack and it just works randomly.